# Database Server is not found. Please verify the login, password and server fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, prestashop, openshift

I have 2 gears in OpenShift configured as follows:

1. application gear, scalable, running PHP 5.3
2. database gear, non scalable, running MySQL Database 5.1 and phpMyAdmin

I am running PrestaShop's installation code on my application gear, and it failed on this code:

install/models/Database.php:

`Db::checkConnection($server, $login, $password, $database, true)`

returns 1.

I am new to OpenShift and not sure if I should use port forwarding, etc.

I run `env | grep OPENSHIFT_MYSQL` on my database gear, get:

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=3306
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.xx.xx.x
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_IDENT=redhat:mysql:5.1:0.2.2
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=XXXXXXX
```

and put those into my prestashop installation config, however, it returns error with `Database Server is not found. Please verify the login, password and server fields (DbPDO)`

I also tried putting MySQL DB on the same gear, run `env | grep OPENSHIFT_MYSQL` on that gear and fill in the settings, but it returns the same error.

Do you have any guide to install and connect MySql DB from a scalable gear? or connect to MySQL DB from the same gear?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the sole purpose 2) is to house the database for for 1), then you can simply embed the mysql db cartridge to 1) (rhc cartridge add) and destroy 2).  When you embed a db to a scalable app, it will be hosted in a separate gear and associated to the same app allowing you to connect directly from the gears with the web framework tier.

Comment: Please note that you won't be able to use phpmyadmin on a scalable app but you can then use port-forwarding from your client machine to connect to the db using a local install of phpmyadmin.

Comment: @NamDuong thanks for the help! Yes, indeed 2) sole purpose is the db for 1). If that's the case, I'll just embed to the scalable php-app

Comment: however, I can't seem to get phpmyadmin working... based on the instruction here `https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift` it seems like I can only access mysql through command line... Is there any guide to get phpmyadmin connected to the remote db? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know what you did here.  Did you create a separate gear on your own running the MySQL cartridge?  If that is the case, you will not be able to reach it from your php scaled gears because of SELinux and the way that applications are protected from directly reaching each other.  You should add the MySQL database to your existing scaled PHP application, it will get put on it's own gear, and you will get MYSQL environment variables like these to use:

```
[phpscaled-cdaley.rhcloud.com 5296d2cc5973cac73800018f]\> env | grep MYSQL
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=62551
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=5296d32550044690010001c3-cdaley.rhcloud.com
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_UUID=5296d32550044690010001c3
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=xxxxxx
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@5296d32550044690010001c3-     cdaley.rhcloud.com:62551/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_DNS=5296d32550044690010001c3-cdaley.rhcloud.com
```

You can see that the OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST is not a fully qualified domain name, and the port is NOT 3306 anymore.  This url/port is reachable from all of your scaled gears.

You COULD make your php scaled application connect to your MySQL gear you spun up by yourself, but you would have to use port forwarding and it gets really messy.  In a scaled application, the databases are put on their own gears anyways.

Also, if you want to run phpMyAdmin, you can upload it yourself along with your other application code (by putting it in git) and configure it using the MySQL environment variables and it will work just fine in a scaled environment, it's just the phpMyAdmin cartridge that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below trick:

*Create a database -> connect to it (here we get error) -> Remove database which has just created.*

Now reconnect we will see that No data exits and Our configuration page suggest create new database with upon name. Success!